# Open PDF file using intent programmatically in android

Tags: android

I have an android app wherein I need to open my pdf file from url. For that, I have used following code to invoke supporting applications to open my pdf file but despite having more than 5 such applications, just two apps e.g. Adobe Reader and Goodgle Drive are listed.

````
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);```

But, I'm in need to open pdf using other compatible apps already installed. Please help resolve the ibid issue.
Thanks
````

Answer (score 1):

**use this**

```
private fun ViewFile(pdfFile: File) {
 Log.e("!!pdfFile",pdfFile.absolutePath)

 val path: Uri
 val pdfIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
 try {
 val m: Method = StrictMode::class.java.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure")
 m.invoke(null)
 } catch (e: Exception) {
 e.printStackTrace()
 }
 path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.toString() + ".provider", pdfFile)

 // path = Uri.parse(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());

 // pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
 pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf")
 pdfIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
 pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
 } else {
 path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile)
 pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf")
 }


 /* Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
 BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
 pdfFile);*/try {
 startActivity(pdfIntent)
 } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
 Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.lblnoapplicationfound), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this simple way to open pdf from url

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
 startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: But without specifying the type of file will simply open the pdf with default app. It wouldn't let us select or change app. In mine case, the pdf was opened in Adobe acrobat with no user intervention.